# Create a standalone application with Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

How do I create a desktop (standalone/Swing) application with Maven?

I'm using Eclipse 3.6.

Comment: What exactly are the issues you face? Maven is a build tool it should have little relevance what you are building, more how you are compiling it.

Take a look at some of the netbeans tutorials. It's pretty easy to change the projects to use maven when their still small.

If its archetypes you are looking for then I'm sure there are a bunch.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Create a Maven project as follows:

   ```
   mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.yourapp.app 
                          -DartifactId=swingapp  
                          -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
   ```
2. Add the following entry to your pom file:

   ```
   <build>
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.3.1</version>
           <configuration>
               <archive>
                   <manifest>
                       <mainClass>com.yourapp.app.YourMainClass</mainClass>
                   </manifest>
               </archive>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   </plugins>
   </build>
   ```
3. Import the project into Eclipse as a Maven project, then run as Java application.

Answer (score 5):

The following works for me:

1. Create a standard Java project
2. Create a source folder "src/main/java"
3. Create a package "testswing" in the source folder
4. Create a class "App" with a main method

   ```
   package testswing;

   import javax.swing.JFrame;

   public class App {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           JFrame f=new JFrame("Hello World");
           f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           f.setVisible(true);
       }  
   }
   ```
5. Convert to a Maven project (through the Configure... Convert to Maven Project right click menu)
6. Ensure the pom.xml contains a manifest that specifies your main class:

   ```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
       <groupId>TestSwing</groupId>
       <artifactId>TestSwing</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <build>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                   <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                   <configuration>
                       <archive>
                           <manifest>
                               <mainClass>testswing.App</mainClass>
                           </manifest>
                       </archive>
                   </configuration>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
       </build>
   </project>
   ```
7. Run a Maven build with the "package" goal (Run As... Maven Build menu)
8. You should get an executable .jar file that runs as a standalone Swing application

Answer (score 4):

```
archetype used?
```

A swing application is a standard JAR so just use the standard archetype:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.yourapp.app \
                       -DartifactId=swingapp     \
                       -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

If you plan to use the standard Swing API only, there aren't no extra dependencies to declare.For extra functionalists you have to use appropriate dependencies in repository

Answer (score 1):

<sub>**UPDATE!**</sub>

[image: New icon] If you get the following error (Apache Maven 3.3.1):

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:create
(default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache
.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:create for parameter #: Cannot create instance 
of interface org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository: org.apache.maven.ar
tifact.repository.ArtifactRepository.<init>() -> [Help 1]
```

Use the following command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.test -DartifactId=AppTest -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

---

You may want to prefer the command line tool for **create** the project and you may want to prefer eclipse for **development**.

1. Create the maven project.

   Navigate to the eclipse workspace directory and use the next command line:

   ```
   mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=com.test -DartifactId=AppTest
   ```
2. Import the project in eclipse:

   In menu **File** > **Import...**, select **Existing Maven Projects**:

   [image: Import Existing Maven Projects]

   Input/**Browse...** the eclipse workspace directory (the directory of the previous step) and select the project:

   [image: Select Maven Projects]

   Enjoy!